# Google Analytics Api Inividual history

Tags: api, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

Can I get a history of a particular user(for example: all page view) using Google Analytics Api through Google Analytics cookie GA1.3.465646922.1425555945 or Client ID

```
ga(function(tracker) {
     var 
        clientID = tracker.get('clientId'),
  });
```

I use php library.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to store the clientId (or the value of the cookie) in a custom dimension, then call the core reporting api including dimension1, pagePath and pageviews.  However, if you have not stored these values in a custom dimension yet, I doubt you can do it for historical data